# is it possible to run the desktop softwares on Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a tablet ( not rooted currently, but can be, if needed). The specs are as follows:

-> 1.5 GHz dual core Cortex A9, 1 Gb RAM and 2 GB internal memory with sd card support. Runs on Android 4.1. 1, USB otg

My requirements are as follows:

1. I am college student and would like to run softwares that I normally run on PC, such as the IDE ( Eclipse etc) and EDA simulation tools
2. If possible Ubuntu touch is preferred.

Recently I heard of 2 projects: Linux on Android and Ubuntu touch

Now my query is, is it possible to run the desktop softwares on Ubuntu touch? It would be great if I could run various IDE and EDA simulation tools on Ubuntu touch without added hardware etc ( apart from keyboard and mouse).
How about Linux on Android project? Can it fulfil my needs?

Take into account that since my internal storage is small, I will need to install software on sd card. Is it supported?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Applications which require X11 will not work, without modification. Applications which have been modified to work properly under strict confinement, and that will work on Mir rather than X11, should work.

As for installation to alternate directories, click packages (the packaging format/system for Ubuntu for devices) installed via the app store scope, will only be installed to a single location. You may do manual installation to install them to a separate location, though. As for deb packages, they may also theoretically be installed to a different root path, but interdependencies between packages may result in broken installations if you do so.

Comment: Whoa. I am unaware of that x11 etc stuff. Just started linux a week back. Do I assume that in my case ( the simulation tools like xilinx ISE and netbeans, eclipse, spice), linux for android is the answer and touch wont work ? Is there a way to simultaneously install both ?

Comment: I think you need to get a real general purpose computer, if you are taking university level CS courses. SD cards are horribly slow, and 2GB is nowhere near enough space to do anything useful these days. Java needs a lot of disk space.

Comment: Well, I have a pc, but cant afford a laptop here. I heard about this project and thought I can instantly get a hybrid device with pc like capabilities without spending a penny. As for storage, i have 32 gb class 10 micro sd, enough for important softwares. Can touch handle my tools, or should I go with full ubuntu ?

Comment: If you've got the bandwidth, a better solution might just be using a VNC client or similar on the tablet, and running the actual software on home PC or university servers. There is an _armhf_ build of standard Ubuntu, and it would be best for running tools such as Eclipse.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions, but please stick to my query. Can ubuntu touch combined with class 10 sd card handle my tools, or should I go with full ubuntu ?